Why batch training with maximum batchsize using PyTorch dataloader exhibits worse performance than inputing entire datasets to the networks?
While experimenting with PyTorch for neural network training, we encounter a choice: Should we load data in batches using PyTorch's DataLoader, or should we input the entire dataset at once directly into the model (No GPU memory issues)? I was thinking that using DataLoader with a batch size equal to the entire dataset should mirror the performance of directly loading the full dataset. However, observations indicate otherwise.
It's observed that when using DataLoader with maximum batch size, the training performance (e.g. loss) tends to be poorer compared to loading the entire dataset directly. Moreover, this method of using DataLoader also seems to consume more time.
As someone new to PyTorch, I find these differences puzzling. Why does training with DataLoader in batches, even when the batch size is at its maximum, yield worse performance than loading all the data directly into the model?
Very appreciate any assistance with unpacking the intricacies of data loading in PyTorch and seeking explanations for these curious behaviors.
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import time


# Set the random seed for reproducibility
torch.manual_seed(0)

# Generate synthetic data
x = torch.linspace(-10, 10, 1000).unsqueeze(1)  # x data tensor
y = x**2 + torch.randn_like(x) * 10  # y data with noise


class SimpleLinearModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleLinearModel, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 10)  # First linear layer
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()        # ReLU activation
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(10, 1)  # Second linear layer to map back to output

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x
    

def train_model(model, loader, optimizer, epochs=2000):
    criterion = nn.MSELoss()
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        for x_batch, y_batch in loader:
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            output = model(x_batch)
            loss = criterion(output, y_batch)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
    print("Loader: Loss is {}".format(loss.item()))
    return model


# Model instances
model_direct = SimpleLinearModel()
model_loader = SimpleLinearModel()

# Optimizers
optimizer_direct = optim.Adam(model_direct.parameters(), lr=0.01)
optimizer_loader = optim.Adam(model_loader.parameters(), lr=0.01)

# DataLoader
dataset = TensorDataset(x, y)
full_batch_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=len(dataset), shuffle=False)   

# Train directly using the full dataset
model_direct.train()
time_start = time.time()
for epoch in range(2000):
    optimizer_direct.zero_grad()
    outputs = model_direct(x)
    loss = nn.MSELoss()(outputs, y)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer_direct.step()

print("Direct: Time is {}".format(time.time() - time_start))
print("Direct: loss is {}".format(loss.item()))


# Train using the DataLoader
model_loader.train()
time_start = time.time()
model_loader = train_model(model_loader, full_batch_loader, optimizer_loader)
print("Loader: Time is {}".format(time.time() - time_start))

# Evaluate and compare
model_direct.eval()
model_loader.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    direct_preds = model_direct(x)
    loader_preds = model_loader(x)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)

plt.scatter(x.numpy(), y.numpy(), s=1)
plt.plot(x.numpy(), direct_preds.numpy(), color='r')
plt.title('Direct Training')
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.scatter(x.numpy(), y.numpy(), s=1)
plt.plot(x.numpy(), loader_preds.numpy(), color='r')
plt.title('Training with DataLoader')
plt.show()



Any answers for the case of worse performance from dataloader?

The differences in time come from the fact the when you have to get a batch from dataloader, you will have to use a for-loop like operator, and doing some data aggregation to make it a tensor again. Modify the direct training part like this, and you will see the time increase (which is still not as slow as loading from dataloader, so dataloader may have some extra steps in checking and ready for distributed learning, ect...
for epoch in tqdm(range(2000)):
    x_ ,y_ = zip(*[(xx, yy) for xx, yy in zip(x,y)])
    x_ = torch.stack(x_)
    y_ = torch.stack(y_)
    optimizer_direct.zero_grad()
    outputs = model_direct(x_)
    loss = nn.MSELoss()(outputs, y_)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer_direct.step()


Thank you for your answer here. Now I get some points of more time consumption.
But I am still curious about the poorer performance caused by dataloader?
Any ideas to this matter?
